# Deleting an array from a multidimensional array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

How would this get done? Assume I have the following

```
arr = [[test, 0, 0, 0], [apples, 0, 9, 8]]
```

I know I would do something like:

```
def delete_me(item)
    arr.each do |a|
        if a[0] == item
            #delete the array containing test
        end
    end
end

delete_me('test')
```

As far as I can see you can only do: `a.remove()` but that leaves me with a empty `[]`,m I don't want that, I want it completely gone.

Comment: Try [Array#delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `delete_if` and match the first term to your argument:

```
arr = [['test', 0, 0, 0], ['apples', 0, 9, 8]]

def delete_me(array, term)
  array.delete_if {|x, *_| x == term }
end
```

(I've included the array as an argument as well, as the execution context is not clear from your post).

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @iamnotmaynard's suggestion:

```
arr.delete_if { |a| a[0] == 'test' }
```

Answer (score 0):

`assoc`.

```
arr.delete(arr.assoc("test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need to remove one or more column**s** that matched a text pattern.

```
col_to_delete = 'test'
arr = [['test','apples','pears'],[2,3,5],[3,6,8],[1,3,1]]
arr.transpose.collect{|a| a if (a[0] != col_to_delete)}.reject(&:nil?).transpose
=> [["apples", "pears"], [3, 5], [6, 8], [3, 1]]
```